# Requiring agricolae

Tags: r, package

How can I require a package called agricolae? I'm getting the following error:

> library(agricolae)
>   Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
>     there is no package called ‘coda’
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘agricolae’

Comment: You should also include the code you are trying to run

Comment: how can I change non writable library to rewritable one?

Comment: I faced this problem and then I updated r from 4.3.3 to 3.4.4 version.

Comment: I used comand: install.packages("agricolae"), istalled but when I use library (agricolae) this error is resulted.  Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘coda’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘agricolae’

Comment: You should install package `coda` then, using `install.packages("coda")` and activate it with `library`. Don't be surprised if you then get the same error message but with yet another dependent package that you need to install... even when I have tried to be complete and used `dependencies=TRUE` in the initial `install.packages` sometimes this still happens and I end up manually installing three... or four... or seven other packages.